# How to call C# none static method in Blazor component from JS file with parameter?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

The Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0#component-instance-examples) explains how to call a component instance methods from a JS code with parameter. In the example, the function in JS file calls from Blazor component by IJSRuntime.

```
// In  razor component
public async Task TriggerDotNetInstanceMethod()
{
    objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    result = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("sayHello2", objRef, name);
}

[JSInvokable]
public string GetHelloMessage(string passedName) => $"Hello, {passedName}!";

// In JS file.
<script>
   window.sayHello2 = (dotNetHelper, name) => {
   return dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('GetHelloMessage', name);
 };
</script>
```

My question is how to call the JSInvokable C# method in a Blazor component with parameter from a JS file by an event. For example, Google map API returns a response with an address and coordinates through an event inside the map in a JS file. I want to pass these details to a none static method in a razor component to have more process on them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understand-javascript-interop-in-blazor/).

Need a global variable and passing our DotNetObjectReference to it. Then we can call invokeMethodAsync through this object variable and call our C# method with parameter. Now, it's working for me!

```
var object;

window.JsFunctionHelper = {MapSuccessResponse: function (instance, address) {
       object = instance;
       return instance.invokeMethodAsync("GetAddress", valuesFromApi);
       }
 };

 function getValuesFromApi() {
      .
      .
      .

      object.invokeMethodAsync("GetAddress", valuesFromApi);
 }
```